# Abbrev Mode - trying to get rid of SPACE character from insertion key

Tags: emacs

I'm having trouble getting rid of the space from the insertion key.

Here's the function for my .emacs file

```
(defun abbrev-backward-char ()
    (backward-char 1) t) ; return non-nil to inhibit insertion of the character
                         ; that triggered the expansion
(put 'abbrev-backward-char 'no-self-insert t)
```

Here's my abbrevs_defs table

```
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table
   '(   
       ("slv" "std_logic_vector" abbrev-backward-char 0)))
```

The problem I'm having is that when I type "slv" it's: first expanding the word, then backspacing, and THEN adding the insertion character.  So I'm left with this: "std_logic_vecto r".

I want it to, instead: expand, add insertion character, and then LASTLY backspace.  So I'm left with "std_logic_vector".

I hope I'm not asking for miracles here.

I've been going at this for hours, it seems so ridiculous that there's not an easier to get rid of then insertion char.

Answer (score 0):

The interface is cleaner is you don't overload space to do abbrev expansion.
Instead overload `dabbrev-expand` <kbd>M-/</kbd> with [hippie-expand](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand).

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip, I'll  be using that in the future!  

I also found out that what I'm trying to do already exists in vhdl-mode. :P  So if I type "s" then hit <tab>, it will already create "std_logic_vector", therefore saving me the trouble. :)  Rookie mistake..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the workaround that I found was to use (signal 'quit nil) at the end of the function called with the abbrev.